# Creating component with changeable inner html

Tags: html, vue.js

We create Vue component

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({});

app.component('header-link',{
    data(){
        return{
            count: 0
        }
    },
    template: `
        <a class="link" href="#">
        </a>
    `
})

app.mount("div#app");
```

But then, if we try:

```html
<header-link id="about">About</header-link>
```

Then "About" inner HTML is being ignored, and element is created instead:

```html
<a class="link" href="#" id="about"></a>
```

Comment: You're looking for [`slot`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).

Comment: @StevenB. Well ... Thanks, it worked, you could write an answer, I will accept that, however, I don't really understand the purpose of slot tag, if it just "enables" adding inner html

Comment: For more complicated components, you may want to distribute the provided content into different places or even have multiple slots.